# How do you save the game in "The Forest"?

Tags: the-forest

I'm unsure how to save the game. How do I do so?

Answer (score 10):

Certain Structures (like houses, treehouses etc.) allow you to save the game and also to sleep.

> Building a **Hunting Shelter**

is the fastes way to achieve this as it only requires few resources to build.

Answer (score 2):

Once you **build a house or cabin or anything you can sleep in**, you're able to save your game

Comment: No, this is wrong, doesn't need to be a cabin or a house, it can be any shelter in which you can rest in sleep. Please fix your answer.